# Windows 10 upgrade vs clean install over Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, clean-install

There are articles about comparing clean vs upgraded installation from older version (like Seven or Eight), but I couldn't find any comparison when you want install a new updated Windows 10 over previous one (happened in case you don't have internet connection, however want to be updated).

Q: What is the cons of upgrading new Windows 10 over older Windows 10 vs clean installation.

Comment: I don't think "windows 10 over windows 10" would be an option. Either you do an installation (installer will clean everything and install from empty disk), or you do a factory restore (or whatever is called). Or of course if you have a newer version, you could upgrade it through Win 10 update menu, but I would not consider it to be an installation.

Comment: Sometimes people have issues with upgrading, other times the process is flawless. It seems to be largely hardware and software dependant. In regards to cons, there isn't any as long as the upgrade goes smoothly.

Comment: The only reason to do a clean installation is to remove all traces of the current installation, which will remove all malware and optimise performance with a clean registry. If this is worth the cost of all the subsequent application and data reinstallations, then it's preferable, but this can be a big task, which is why most people prefer to upgrade, whether by Windows Updates or from a Windows-over-Windows installation. I have not infrequently needed to use Windows-over-Windows when Windows Updates fail repeatedly.

Comment: @Máté Juhász how a factory restore will update my system? The problem about update files is it's huge! I don't think some small changes would be so big (unless they included various hardwares, why Linux apt-get is not so??), so I've concluded to block Update, save bandwidths and periodically get an ISO and update my system.

Comment: There is no difference between an upgrade installation of a Windows 10 and a clean installation of Windows 10.  In both cases Windows 10 is installed, if you choose to keep files they are moved after the installation is completed (behind the scenes), check my answer for detailed information on how windows Reset works to better understand the process (it’s the same process) basically

Answer (score 0):

The similarities are very much the same as with previous versions of Windows.

An upgrade or installing Windows on top of itself will overwrite system files with data from the installation media. User data will be retained.

A clean install is just like it sounds. You will start fresh and lose all files and user data. This will reinstall Windows from scratch. This is like starting over.

Comment: I know what is upgrade and clean installation, what I don't know is the cons in case of windows 10 over windows 10. If you read the articles, people scream to clean install and upgrade is not advisable.